# Confusion about the conjugate (square roots)

Tags: radicals

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) Wikipedia article it says:
"In mathematics, the **conjugate** of an expression of the form $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is $a-b\sqrt{d}$, provided that $\sqrt{d}$ does not appear in $a$ and $b$."

Why can't $\sqrt{d}$ appear in $a$ and $b$?
In my textbook it is defied like Wikipedia did it except that it didn't say that $\sqrt{d}$ can't appear in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That wiki article is too short. Your textbook may have the more rigorous Definition + Context. Basically , we may sometimes want $a$ & $b$ integers , we may sometimes want $a$ & $b$ rationals , we may sometimes want $a$ & $b$ reals , Etc. That wiki is stating that $a$ & $b$ should not contain the root term. Eg with $2\sqrt{3}+5\sqrt{3}$ , we can not state that the conjugate is $2\sqrt{3}-5\sqrt{3}$ ; rather we must make it $0+7\sqrt{3}$ to get the conjugate $0-7\sqrt{3}$ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case Wikipedia's explanation is quite poor.

Let's take a step back. Consider a polynomial
$$
P(X)=X^d+a_1X^{d-1}+a_2X^{d-2}+\cdots+a_d
$$
and assume:

- the coefficients $a_i$ are **rational numbers**;
- the polynomial is **irreducible**, meaning that it admits no decomposition $P(X)=A(X)B(X)$ where $A(X)$ and $B(X)$ are both non constant.

Then it is known (essentially by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra) that $P(X)$ admits $d$ different roots $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_d$ in the complex numbers, none of which is a rational number. A root of a polynomial $P(X)$ is some number $\alpha$ such that $P(\alpha)=0$.

We say that two complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are **conjugated** if they both appear among the roots of a polynomial as above.

Back to square roots.

When the degree of the polynomial is $2$, i.e.
$$
P(X)=X^2+aX+b,
$$
the roots are $\alpha_{1,2}=\frac12\left(-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}\right)$ so that in fact one root is transformed into the other (conjugation) by switching sign to the square root.

The "radical not appearing in $a$" clause should be read "$a$ and $b$ are rational numbers".

A more general situation is that when the polynomia $P(X)$ is allowed to have coefficients in just any [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), but let's keep it simple for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

In front of a radical sign we have an implied $\pm$ sign.

If a radical appears in $a$ or $b$ then it would make for four instead of two results and there would be ambiguity.

They would arise as roots from a fourth order and not a quadratic equation with real coefficients.

It is better to say, imho, that :

"$a-b\sqrt{d}$, provided that the radical does not appear in $a$ and $b$ real numbers"

Comment: There is no implied ± in front of a radical.

Comment: In this context I mean in the solutions to a quadratic equation the roots always  appear in pairs like $p \pm \sqrt{q}$ including its conjugate.